# How to configure 16x2 character LCD to work with 8bit?

Tags: lcd, library

I have the [LiquidCrystal](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal) library installed but all the examples are for 4bit connection, I want to drive the LCD with 8bit.

In [LiquidCrystal.cpp](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/master/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp) file it says;

> When the display powers up, it is configured as follows:
>
> DL = 1;  8-bit interface data

But what's is the function, should it be like this: `LiquidCrystal DL(1);`? where and how should I call `DL = 1;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "do" anything to enable 8 bit. As it says *when the device powers up the DL bit in the configuration is already set, enabling 8 bit*.

You just need to wire it for 8 bit and specify all 8 bits of wiring in the constructor.

The manual entry for the constructor shows you what parameters you can specify:

- https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/liquidcrystal/liquidcrystal/